typst how to set line thickness in CeTZ `plot`?
I am trying to set the line thickness of a plot using cetz.
#set page(height: auto)

#import "@preview/cetz:0.2.2"

#set align(center)
#cetz.canvas({
  import cetz.plot
  plot.plot(
    size: (14, 4), 
    axis-style: "school-book",
    x-tick-step: none, 
    y-tick-step: none, 
    x-minor-step: 0.00001,
    x-break: true,
    {
      plot.add(
        domain: (-10, 10), 
        samples: 1000,
        style: (paint:red, thickness: 50pt),
        x => if x < -1 {0} else if x>= -1 and x<=1 {(x+1) / 2} else {1}
      )
      plot.add(
        domain: (-10, 10), 
        samples: 1000,
        x => if x < -1 {1} else if x>= -1 and x<=1 {1 - (x+1) / 2} else {0}
      )
    }
  )
})
#set align(left)

I don't know how to set the type parameter despite trying to find how to in the docs.

I think the style parameter takes a dictionary with fill and stroke styles, meaning it should be style: (stroke: (paint: red, thickness: 50pt))
